# Errors while building Cassandra debian package

Tags: cassandra, debian

I've been following steps in here -> http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging

Done everything but it seems I can't build the packages. After executing dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us

All I get is this:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): 
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): 
tail: cannot open `debian/changelog' for reading: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: tail of debian/changelog gave error exit status 1
```

What's the problem? I think I got the correct java version either:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be running `dpkg-buildpackage` from inside the `debian/` directory.  You should be running it from the top-level directory.

If that's not the case, make sure the `debian/` directory exists at all.  I believe you need to do a source checkout; the downloadable packages won't include it.  The easiest way to do that is `git clone git://github.com/apache/cassandra.git`.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when the debian directory is a symlink.